# Ubuntu shuts down automatically on nodejs installation

Tags: node.js

I am trying to work on node.js on my Ubuntu 12.04. However everytime I try to install it, Ubuntu shuts down automatically.
Here are the steps I am trying to do:

```
$ apt-get -y install libssl-dev git-core pkg-config build-essential curl gcc g++ checkinstall

$ wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.11/node-v0.8.11.tar.gz
$ tar -zxf node-v0.8.11.tar.gz

$ cd node-v0.8.11
$ ./configure && make && checkinstall --install=yes --pkgname=nodejs --pkgversion "0.8.11" --default
```

Capturing the terminal output also doesn't seem to be useful since it does not provide any reason for shutdown.
Is there something I am missing in installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This **may** be a hardware-related problem. Please check that your memory is all right before doing other stuff.

Secondly, this may point to some kernel problems, of which you may learn from system log files.

Thirdly, you are generally better off doing the various stages sequentially to find the exact crash stage instead of combining them with `&&`.

Now, on to the node.js installation. I have been less than successful with checkinstall; however, I have definitely liked [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm), and used it to compile and package (it can do both .deb and .rpm ones) Node.JS and then install it

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
mkdir -p /tmp/nodejs
make install DESTDIR=/tmp/nodejs
fpm -s dir -t deb -n nodejs -v 0.8.11 -C /tmp/nodejs -p nodejs-VERSION_ARCH.deb usr
```

HTH